# I want to override Telerik methods and events

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik

I have  Telerik control Scheduler. I want to override below method:

```
private void radSchedulerDemo_AppointmentEditDialogShowing(object sender, AppointmentEditDialogShowingEventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = "CHECKED";
}
```

How do I override this method? It's automatically opened in its own Telerik Form when I call a double click event. I want to use my own form instead.

Comment: http://www.telerik.com/support/winforms

Answer (score 1):

The event arguments expose the `AppointmentEditDialog` property, which you can set. It will accept an object which implements the `IEditAppointmentDialog` interface.

This is how you replace the default dialog with yours.